# RStudio conflict error with R 3.5.0 and Dropbox

Tags: r, knitr, dropbox, pandoc

I recently upgraded two different PC to R 3.5x and I noticed that RStudio, used in Sync with Dropbox, raises the following errors when I try to compile pandocs or to pdflatex:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
can't open this connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> png -> .handleSimpleError -> h -> cat -> 
file
In addition: warning message:
1: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
unable to open file 'reportDucret_files/figure-docx/ipss1-1.png' for writing
2: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : opening device failed
3: In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
cannot open file 'reportDucret.knit.md': Permission denied
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heuristically, I found that the issue is likely caused by anti virus softwares that block files programs pandoc pandoc-citeproc and rterm as randomware false positives. I had that issue with Bitdefender. Dropbox does not